# Parentheses surrounding sub-query alias, syntax change from 5.6?

Tags: mysql, sql

Our framework's query builder automatically wraps the FROM clause in parentheses; including sub-queries.

The following used to work with 5.6 but when trying to upgrade to 8 is throwing a syntax error.

`SELECT t.* FROM ((SELECT * FROM table_name) t)`

It works in 8 without the outer parentheses. I can't find any references to this change in the logs or on the web. Does anyone know when this was implemented or if it is in any way configurable in Mysql?

Trying to avoid changing the query builder or finding all the uses of sub-queries at this point. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO: Use joins instead subselects where not neccessary. A subselect should return only exact one row.

Comment: Thanks Markus. The query itself is performing as intended and at the moment we're trying to avoid changing the query builder. This issue is with the change in syntax for parentheses in Mysql DML.

Comment: Why not remove the redundant super query?

Comment: The code in the question is just to demonstrate the syntax change. The actual query is complex and could be numerous throughout the application.

Comment: I'm surprised this ever worked.  I thought derived tables always had to have an alias, so you need an alias for the outer parentheses as well . . . But I can see that it did indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) -- which has not changed -- it looks like this should be allowed.  The relevant part of the documentation is highlighted using asterisks below:

> ```
> table_reference: {
>     table_factor
>   | joined_table
> }
>
> table_factor: {
>     tbl_name [PARTITION (partition_names)]
>         [[AS] alias] [index_hint_list]
>   | [LATERAL] table_subquery [AS] alias [(col_list)]
>   | **( table_references )**
> }
> ```

Note that this says that a table reference can be surrounded in parentheses.  These are separate from the the parentheses used for a subquery.

Based on this, there would appear to be a bug in MySQL 8.0 -- either in the documentation or the code.  I guess when they added new functionality for things like lateral joins into the tokenizer, this dropped out.

Knowing that it is a bug doesn't really help you solve your real problem.  MySQL 5.6 was behaving correctly based on the documentation, even if this construct doesn't work in other databases.

I notice that MariaDB 10.4 doesn't have this problem.  Perhaps upgrading to MariaDB would work (it should otherwise have very similar functionality).